# Ways of Importing Modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused in the methodologies of importing Modules in Python and stumbled onto the following.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
```

Was Wondering how these two commands are different from one another?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

In practice, a quick answer is that if you import several modules in which some of the functions may have the same name(let's say .addition()). By importing in the manner of:

```
import module1 as md1
import module2 as md2
```

you can call md1.addition() and md2.addition() without trouble.

But if you import it as

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
```

you will get confused when you call addition().

Besides, if you are not familiar with the module, you could accidentally define a function which has the same name in the imported module and overwrites it. So, I think from module import * should be avoided unless you have a reason for that.